# How to add CSS and Js to a wordpress child theme

Tags: javascript, php, css, wordpress

I'm trying to add my `css` and `js` to my Wordpress child theme, but none of them gets picked up.

The themes are being added recursively from some set folders.

What could be it that I'm getting wrong?

Thank you all in advance.

**functions.php**

```
<?php

/* Add Scripts */

if ( ! function_exists('rev_cust_scripts')) {

    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'rev_cust_scripts' );

    function rev_cust_scripts() {
        $css_paths = array("layout", "js");
        $scripts_stack = [];

        foreach ($css_paths as &$value) {

            $dir = get_stylesheet_directory() . '/' . $value;
            $iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dir), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST );

            foreach ( $iterator as $path ) {
                if ( ! $path -> isDir() ) {
                    $path_parts = pathinfo($path);
                    $file_parts = $path_parts['extension'];

                    if ( !in_array($file_parts, array('css','js'), true ) ) 
                        continue;

                    switch ($file_parts) {
                        case 'css':
                        $file_name = basename($path, '.css');
                        break;
                        case 'js':
                        $file_name = basename($path, '.js');
                        break;
                    }

                    $pages_base = "/opt/lampp/htdocs/projects/wordpress_projects/liz_bloggable";
                    $server_pages_base = "http://localhost/projects/wordpress_projects/liz_bloggable";

                    $url = str_replace($pages_base, $server_pages_base, $path);

                    $array_item = array('script' => $file_parts, 'handle' => $file_name, 'src' => $url);
                    array_push($scripts_stack, $array_item);
                }
            }
        }

        doAttachScripts($scripts_stack);
    }

    function doAttachScripts($scripts) {
        foreach ($scripts as $key => $child_array) {
            if (is_array($child_array)) {
                $script = $child_array['script'];

                switch ($script) {
                    case 'css':
                    wp_enqueue_style($child_array['handle'], $child_array['src']);
                    break;

                    case 'js' :
                    wp_enqueue_script( $child_array['handle'], $child_array['src'], array('jquery'));
                    break;
                }
                unset($scripts[$key]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: http://themes.simplethemes.com/skeleton/tutorials/how-to-add-custom-css-and-javascript-using-a-child-theme/

Comment: I've tried that approach @zod, but I't won't work.

Comment: Is `$scripts` arriving ok at `doAttachScripts()`?